# How to increase the dataset?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, dataset, computer-vision, face-recognition

I am doing a project on face recognition. I have a dataset containing image of 21 actors(each 150). Now I want to increase the no. of image of each actor to 300+ for the training purpose. How can I do it using MATLAB. Some solutions can be we can vary the contrast/brightness level of each image. But what are some other factors through which I can increase the no. of images.

Answer (score 0):

One option is for you to flip the images: If a person is looking to the right, after the flip he will be looking to the left.

Further more, depending on your possible toolkit and set of skills, you could do some more advanced technique. If you can find some interesting characteristic from the pictures, like: eyes, nose, mouth, background. With those, you could make some intelligent transformations - swap peoples eyes, change the background, switch noses.

There are some particular objects of the faces which you could also distort - like the eyes and nose - stretch them. Maybe for bold guys you could built some synthetic hair, and so on...

You could do the contrast/brightness level change, but usually it doesn't do so well, as your features probably doesn't have (almost) anything to do with it, so it will just be a duplication of your data.

Anyway, as it's not a very large data set, if you don't have the set of skills to pull the more advances options I proposed, or the time to deal with it, you can make some of those stuff manually. It won't take you as much as you think. And usually, with that amount of data, this will give a good boost to your results.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "data augmentation". Common transformations are mirroring (flipping left / right side of the image) and rotation of the image. You might also be able to zoom (crop) a part of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe scaled versions with the rotated ones may help. If your features are not robust to the  changes such as lightning contras etc you can modfy the images accordingly.